# Dependency injection with dynamic parameter

Tags: php, dependency-injection

So I have done some searching on here but I cannot find the answer...

I have the following class:

```
class SomeCrmService
{
    public function __construct($endpoint, $key)
    {
        $this->request = new Request($endpoint);
        $this->request->setOption(CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key);
        $this->request->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-type : application/json;", 'Accept : application/json'
        ));
        $this->request->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
        $this->request->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    }
```

The problem I have is that I wanted to inject `Request` so that I could change the library I was using and it would be easier to mock when testing. I needed to pass in the `$endpoint` var which could be (customer, contact, etc) so I thought this was the only option to do it like the above. Is there a way to make this code slightly better and inject Request and use a mutator or something to set the `$endpoint` var?

Thanks

Comment: What if you just added a `->getEndpoint()` method to `Request` and then just passed in `Request $request`?

Comment: The `Request` class is a third party so I am guessing to do that I should really make an interface right?

Comment: Right, just make an interface or adapter. Call it `EndpointRequest` or something! You can even make it extend `Request`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend an approach like this, where you extend the third-party `Request` class and allow it to accept an `$endpoint` along with a getter:

```
<?php

class EndpointRequest extends Request
{
    protected $endpoint;

    public function __construct($endpoint, $key)
    {
        $this->setOption(CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key);
        $this->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-type : application/json;", 'Accept : application/json'
        ));
        $this->setOption(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
        $this->setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    }

    public function getEndpoint()
    {
        return $this->endpoint;
    }
}

class SomeCrmService
{
    public function __construct(EndpointRequest $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[Factory](https://github.com/enumag/DesignPatternsPHP/tree/master/FactoryMethod)** design pattern:

```
<?php

class RequestFactory {

    public function create($endpoint) {
        return new Request($endpoint);
    }

}

class SomeCrmService
{
    public function __construct($endpoint, $key, RequestFactory $requestFactory)
    {
        // original solution
        // $this->request = new Request($endpoint);
        // better solution
        $this->request = $requestFactory->create($endpoint);

        // here comes the rest of your code
    }

}
```

By using the *factory design pattern* you don't have to extend other classes - because in fact you dont want to extend them. You are not adding new functionality, your desire is to have testable environment).